# What happens to my facebook data when I deactivate my account?

Tags: privacy

Facebook's policy explains me that technically I own the information that I share on facebook. It is I who chooses to share my data to a certain group of people.

However, as I deactivate my account, who owns my facebook data? Also, should I be concerned about the privacy of my data which I have already shared in facebook?

Comment: This question might be closed or put on hold because of "vendor-specific" or it's a law questions, maybe in http://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Azteca I believe this has to do with user privacy. Had I tried to make it too generic, the question would have been "too broad for an answer"

Comment: This is off-topic: *who owns your data* is not technical. You should find the answer in the terms and conditions of Facebook and you should have agreed to these terms by using Facebook.  If you don't understand what you've agreed to ask at law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I would still argue that this is on topic. There i a highly voted similar question answered here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/is-facebook-allowed-to-sell-give-your-information-away-to-anyone-willing-to-buy?rq=1

Comment: Also infosec isn't all about tech either. Topics such as social engineering may not be technical but are part of infosec

Comment: @spunkpike: I think the other questions actually answers what you ask for: technically you are the one which owns the data unless you have given permission to share these data (which you have for shared data) or unless some legal authority requests these data. Still, this forum is no place to legally interpret terms and conditions. From infosec view the answer is: know whom to trust because there might be a difference between what they claim to do, what they really do, what the need to do for legal reasons and how good they are able to protect your data against theft.

Comment: "_should I be concerned about the privacy of my data which I have already shared in facebook_"? YES!!!